# How fix unicode error in python when getting data from server

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have following text in server(in hi_how_are_you_guys.html file ). let it

**Det är framförallt på de större lekplatser**

now i am fetching this data by following code

```
result = requests.get("http://localhost/hi_how_are_you_guys.html")
```

i am saving like this

```
open("res.txt",'w').write(result.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Now res.txt look like

**Det Ã¤r framfÃ¶rallt pÃ¥ de stÃ¶rre lekplatser**

Producing unicode  error when i am trying

```
open("res.txt",'w').write(result.text)
```

How can i save string exactly like in server ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `open("res.txt",'w').write(result.text.encode(result.encoding))` or `open("res.txt",'w').write(result.content)`.